# React / onClick function doesn't loop through if/else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, event-listener

I'm trying to get the button to randomly return the alerts in the condition function. however, it doesn't loop through, so it returns the same alert on every click. it only varies if the code reruns (page refresh). What am I missing?

```
const headsOrTails = Math.random() < 0.5;

class Button extends React.Component {

condition() {
  if (headsOrTails === true) {
    alert ('Going Out!');
  } else {
    alert ('ChillZone');
  }
}

render() {
  return 
    <button className="button" onClick={this.condition}>
     WHAT SHOULD WE DO TONIGHT?
    </button>;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `const headsOrTails = Math.random() < 0.5;` statement is executed once. To make it work you can wrap that into a function and call it instead of `headsOrTails === true`:

```js
const headsOrTails = () => (Math.random() < 0.5);

class Button extends React.Component {

  condition() {
    if (headsOrTails()) {
      alert ('Going Out!');
    } else {
      alert ('ChillZone');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="button" onClick={this.condition}>
        WHAT SHOULD WE DO TONIGHT?
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But, we don't need to wrap the return part with parentheses. Duh! You are talking about wrapping it into a function. I hadn't seen it was not a function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue might be that you are setting the coin flip once.  Try adding a function to call the coinflip and run the condition on that function.